# Deploy shiny: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am trying to deploy a shiny app to shinyapps.io however I keep getting this error message in my logs: `Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"`.

In my UI, I have `library(dplyr)` loaded which is the package for the `filter` function. The app works as it should on my local machine. Why do I keep getting this error message when I try to deploy the app?

Here is an example of the app that works locally

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

data <- tibble(
  site = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  date = as.Date(c("2005-06-15", "2005-06-15", "2006-06-15", "2006-06-15", "2007-06-15", "2007-06-15", "2008-06-15", "2008-06-15", "2009-06-15", "2009-06-15", "2005-06-15", "2005-06-15", "2006-06-15", "2006-06-15", "2007-06-15", "2007-06-15", "2008-06-15", "2008-06-15", "2009-06-15", "2009-06-15")),
  Variable = c("temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph", "temperature", "ph"),
  Value = c(20.9, 7.27, 20.8, 6.98, 20.1, 7.08, 18.0, 6.99, 20.6, 6.72, 19.9, 6.92, 19.8, 6.92, 18.5, 6.99, 19.5, 7.22, 20.4, 7.15)
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Time Series Viewer"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Time Series", tabName = "time_series", icon = icon("chart-line"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "time_series",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = "Time Series",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 2,
            selectInput("siteInput", "Select Site", choices = unique(data$site)),
            selectInput("variableInput", "Select Variable", choices = unique(data$Variable))
          ),
          box(
            title = "Plot",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 10,
            plotOutput("timeSeriesPlot", height = "700px")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$timeSeriesPlot <- renderPlot({
    filteredData <- data %>%
      filter(site == input$siteInput, Variable == input$variableInput)
    
    variableName <- unique(filteredData$Variable)
    yLabel <- ifelse(variableName == "temperature", expression(Water~Temperature~(degree*C)),variableName)
    
    ggplot(filteredData, aes(x = date, y = Value)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = "", y = yLabel) +
      scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 year") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black", angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black")) +
      ggtitle(paste("Site:", input$siteInput))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note: I have saved the UI and server as their own scripts in their own folder. The server script does not include the `shinyApp()` at the end like the example above has.

Also here are the logs

```
2023-06-29T14:21:50.530600+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: LANG: C.UTF-8
2023-06-29T14:21:50.530608+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Working directory: /srv/connect/apps/test
2023-06-29T14:21:50.530858+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Using R 4.2.1
2023-06-29T14:21:50.530876+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.2.1/lib/R
2023-06-29T14:21:50.531180+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Content will use current R environment
2023-06-29T14:21:50.531208+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: R_LIBS: (unset)
2023-06-29T14:21:50.531231+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: .libPaths(): /opt/R/4.2.1/lib/R/library
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541641+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: shiny version: 1.7.2
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541670+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: httpuv version: 1.6.6
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541674+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541678+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: knitr version: (none)
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541681+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: jsonlite version: 1.8.4
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541684+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541688+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: htmltools version: 0.5.5
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541709+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: reticulate version: (none)
2023-06-29T14:21:50.541714+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2023-06-29T14:21:50.943328+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Starting R with process ID: '35'
2023-06-29T14:21:50.943727+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Shiny application starting ...
2023-06-29T14:21:50.975621+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:42161
2023-06-29T14:21:53.259905+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Attaching package: ‘lubridate’
2023-06-29T14:21:53.260569+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2023-06-29T14:21:53.260594+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     date, intersect, setdiff, union
2023-06-29T14:21:53.603263+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
2023-06-29T14:21:53.603567+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
2023-06-29T14:21:53.603593+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     filter, lag
2023-06-29T14:21:53.603842+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
2023-06-29T14:21:53.603866+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
2023-06-29T14:21:53.763557+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’
2023-06-29T14:21:53.763800+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2023-06-29T14:21:53.763836+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     box
2023-06-29T14:21:54.880132+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]: Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912458+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:   184: filter
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912485+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:   183: %>%
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912489+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:   182: renderPlot [/srv/connect/apps/test/server.R#3]
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912499+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:   180: func
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912509+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:   140: drawPlot
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912512+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:   126: <reactive:plotObj>
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912516+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:   110: drawReactive
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912535+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:    97: renderFunc
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912558+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:    96: output$timeSeriesPlot
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912575+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:    15: <Anonymous>
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912594+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:    13: fn
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912603+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     8: retry
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912621+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     7: connect$retryingStartServer
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912627+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     6: eval
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912647+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     5: eval
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912652+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     4: eval
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912676+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     3: eval
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912681+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     2: eval.parent
2023-06-29T14:21:54.912704+00:00 shinyapps[9384275]:     1: local
```

**Update 1**: I have tried using `dplyr::filter` in the server but that did not resolve the issue and it generated the same error in the logs with the exception that 184 is now `184: dplyr::filter`

Comment: Your app works for me as-is without errors, it shows a plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMWIc.png). That kind of error is common when you use common function names for data in development but define them differently in production; specifically, `dplyr::filter(data, ...)` if `data` is not defined as a frame will be calling it on the function `base::data`, which is clearly not what is intended (and fails). Add `browser()` in that reactive and see what `data` looks like. If it is a frame, step through the code to see where next it fails.

Comment: I stumbled upon an answer. When I split the UI and server into separate R scripts, I added the data to the UI script but did not add it to the server script. Once I added the data to the server script and deployed the app, it worked.

Comment: Ahh, yes, you may consider a `global.R` script for components that are shared between them. (Or just put it in the `server.R` file.)

Comment: I've done something like this several times: my real code doesn't work, but when I reduce the problem for SO, I then start a fresh R instance and try the code in my question verbatim; when it works, I have a better idea of how to determine which of the differences are likely culprits (i.e., _here_ you have one shiny file, _really_ you have two files). I have numerous questions I've posed completely on StackOverflow only to solve before hitting "Post" for reasons very close to this. Glad you found your issue, good luck!